# In Snowflake dataframes, is there an equivalent to pandas.apply function?

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to apply functions to specific column in snowflake, but I do not see in the documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/index.html.

Example: `df['id'].apply(lambda x: add(x))`

I tried a workaround to convert the Snowflake dataframe to Pandas with `to_pandas()`, but writing it back into snowflake messes up the timestamp formats

Comment: It's not available yet, but it is being reviewed internally. I don't have a timeline for it though.

Comment: thanks @Sergiu. Btw, do you know how to maintain timestamp formats from snowflake to pandas back to snowflake?

Comment: Do you have a specific example at which I can look at?

Comment: @Sergiu I fixed it by using the same workaround here https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/600.

btw, I have another issue, seems that dbt pandas randomly changes the column length. Eg, my original column length is varchar(32), but after reading into a dataframe and writing it back, it becomes varchar(16777216) which is the max. Any idea to enforce this in python? I know in SQL we can CAST

Comment: Are you using Snowpark? Then we have a function `cast` as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/working-with-dataframes#casting-a-column-object-to-a-specific-type)

Comment: @Sergiu I tried that, but it doesnt work. When writing to Snowflake, it still makes it to the max

Comment: I am not sure, maybe it's something from DBT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can create user-defined functions in Snowpark.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/creating-udfs

This is from the docs as a temporary function:

```
from snowflake.snowpark.types import IntegerType
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf

add_one = udf(lambda x: x+1, return_type=IntegerType(), input_types=[IntegerType()], name="my_udf", replace=True)
```

Here is another example, but for a permanent function:

```
@udf(name="minus_one", is_permanent=True, stage_location="@my_stage", replace=True)

def minus_one(x: int) -> int:
return x-1
```

And then you call them like this:

```
df = session.create_dataframe([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).to_df("a", "b")
df.select(add_one("a"), minus_one("b")).collect()

[Row(MY_UDF("A")=2, MINUS_ONE("B")=1), Row(MY_UDF("A")=4, MINUS_ONE("B")=3)]
```